# wordpress function: using str_replace to strip css in head

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm currently trying to delete/comment a markup of  in the head section of wordpress.

Here's my function.

```
function strip_style() { ?>
    <?php

    $commented_style = str_replace("<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/wp-content/themes/headway-208/style.css" />", "<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/wp-content/themes/headway-208/style.css" /> -->", $rawstring);

    echo commented_style;

    ?>
<?php
}

add_action('wp_head', 'strip_style', 1);
```

I can't also use `wp_enqueue_style` and `wp_deregister_style` since the line i am trying to remove is hard-coded with the parent theme.

Basically I want to disable the default css (styles.css) its loading so I can use my own style and not override the default style.

Please advice if my approach of using str_replace() is good or not. Can you suggest an alternative?

Thanks!

Comment: I think your time would be better spent if you just create a new stylesheet that overrides the main stylesheet where necessary.

Comment: hmm.. I'll take your point. but I trying to avoid that route because I don't want to end-up having a stylesheet like this.

Comment: body.custom {....} .custom p {...} .custom a {...}, I find this very messy. so If there's just an option in the server side that can just turn that specific css of, Id be preferring that.

Comment: Yes, but web dev is often messy :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just copy header.php file in your child theme and edit out what you do not want to appear.
If you have header.php in both child and parent theme, the one in child theme will be used. That counts for all files. If you want to edit any of parent theme files just copy it into child theme and edit them there.

As far as css is conserned, in head first the parent theme style.css will be linked and below it child theme style.css so every rule with same specificity in child theme will override parent theme rule, no need for any mambo-jumbo dirty magic.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not fully understanding, but why don't you just copy the existing theme folder, rename it and make your own theme by wiping the style.css and start again as you want?

In any case, if you must do the str_replace(), your code is all wrong.  Firstly, your PHP tags are all over the place, and you can't nest them.  Secondly, your strings won't parse properly because you are using double quotes inside a double-quoted string.  Fixed and simplified:

```
<?php

function strip_style() {
    $link = '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/wp-content/themes/headway-208/style.css" />';
    echo str_replace($link, '<!-- ' . $link . '-->', $rawstring);

    // But where does $rawstring come from?
}

?>
```

.

```
<?php

    add_action('wp_head', 'strip_style', 1);

?>
```

Comment: Hi BadHorsie, thanks! I am creating a child theme based on headwaythemes. By default headway gives you basic styling of your site (style.css). Headway suggest to do prepend a class of ".custom" to you custom style. so it would look something like this. body.custom {...} or .custom p {...}. for me I find it very dirty, where as If its possible i'll just disable that css in the server-side. and I can now use my custom css in a clean slate and no prepend classes.

Comment: the "$rawstring" is also my confusion and problem. how do i get that?